# Traverse depsgraph in Python?

Tags: python, blend-files, depsgraph

[`Context().evaluated_depsgraph_get()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.evaluated_depsgraph_get) returns a [`Depsgraph()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Depsgraph.html) object.

`.debug_stats()` and `.debug_relations_graphviz()` can then be used to export information about the dependency graph and its relationships to text and visual formats:

```
>>> d.debug_stats()
'Approx 97 Operations, 93 Relations, 63 Outer Nodes'
```

[image]

---

**Is there a way to access and traverse this same information using the Python API?**